# How to pattern match different files across multiple directories

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to sign multiple files that exist in different folders. Is this possible in a single try?

The files I am trying to match look like this:

```
bin/release/file1.exe
bin/release/file1.a.dll
bin/release/file1.b.dll
folder1/bin/release/file2.dll
```

Using [Azure DevOps File matching patterns reference guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops#pattern-syntax), I've tried the following to reference file1*.*, but it's only finding `file1.exe`.

```
bin/release/file1.*(exe|dll)
```

Even if I get that to work, how would I add file2.dll to the mix? And is there a way to test file pattern matching without having to kick off a build every time?

Comment: Maybe `file1*`?

Comment: what about * file *?

Comment: That would work but there are .config, .pdb files I don't think need to be signed.  Or does it matter?